# Discord Rich embed reaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot in js. I have a rich embed but I don't know how to react to it. The `message.react('emoji name thing')` doesn't work.
code:

```
var pollEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle(message.author.username + " asks " + args)
                .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            message.channel.send(pollEmbed);
            pollEmbed.react("✔")
```

Comment: please show the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't react to a `RichEmbed` object, only a `message`. Use the following code to react to the newly sent *message* instead...

```js
message.channel.send(pollEmbed)
.then(m => m.react('✔'));
```

Comment: so with my code, I should do this:
`message.channel.send(pollEmbed);
  .then(m => m.react('✔')`

Comment: Exactly like I showed above. Just copy and paste. There shouldn't be a semicolon before `.then`.